# Add shortcut to nowhere

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, filesystems

How to add a shortcut in Windows that leads to nowhere as the target (without producing an error)?

When the shortcut is opened it should do/execute nothing. The important thing is that the shortcut must have a specific name and must be present under that name.

---

Background: An executable expects this shortcut do be present and creates a new one if not so. When it does it sets an unwanted target.

Answer (score 0):

One solution I found was to add `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c` as the target.

This starts a [`cmd` window](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/cmd), executes nothing and closes it afterwards.

Potentially there are more elegant solutions for this.